# Where can I find the phone numbers of my contacts on an iPhone 5C?

Tags: contacts, iphone

I just bought an iPhone 5C. I can't figure out how to make a call. My contact list was uploaded to the new phone but there are no phone numbers listed. Email addresses are listed for some of my contacts.

Do I need to go to a different screen or do I need to manually add phone numbers?

Comment: Did the answer help any?  Any update on the problem you are having with your contacts?

Answer (score 1):

When you select a contact, their phone number should show up towards the top.

[image: Contact]

If it doesn't show a phone number, it's possible that the phone numbers didn't import. It's also possible that there could be multiple contacts for a single person. You can also try and dial a phone number of a contact in your list and see if the name shows up below it.

[image: dial a number]